# First Tuesday PHP

Tags: php, date

The `first_tuesday()` function should return the date of the first Tuesday of year, but especially in the case of 2011 it returns a wrong value. how to Fix the code so it works in all cases

```
function first_tuesday($year){

    $first_january = mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$year);
    $day_week = date("w",$first_january );
    $first_tuesday = $first_jan + ((2 - $day_week) % 7)* 86400;
    return date("d/m/Y",$first_tuesday);
}
```

Comment: Can you write the variable names in English so it's easier for us to understand what you're trying to do?

Comment: done.  edited it into english sorry about that

Comment: Please remember to accept an answer by clicking on a check mark beside one of the answers if you have found a solution to your problem here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/datetime) class instead:

```
function first_tuesday($year){
    $day = new DateTime(sprintf("First Tuesday of January %s", $year));
    return $day->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

Usage:

```
echo first_tuesday(2011);
```

Output:

```
04/01/2011
```

Comment: You probably meant `return` instead of `echo` in your function. :)

Comment: @rink.attendant.6: Right. Fixed it, thanks!

Comment: by the way check this code $exclus=array(1,4);

function hasard(){

 $resultat=rand(1,10);
 return $resultat;
}

echo "Nombre au hasard : ".hasard()."\n";

Comment: @user3172273: That's a different question. Please post it as such. Click on the [Ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Make sure you include ALL the relevant details, and include the expected output in your question. Also, most of the users on this site don't speak <insert whatever language you used above>, so I suggest you post the question (and code) in English. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

`strtotime` is clever enough to get what you want:

```
function first_tuesday($year){
  return date('d/m/Y', strtotime("first Tuesday of January $year"));
}
```

Comment: No it's not. On my machine (PHP 5.5.3) your code returns "07/01/2014"

Comment: No, this is not correct. Your function will return `07/01/2014` -- but the actual value is `04/01/2011`.

Comment: 07/01/2014 is correct though?  For the year 2014.

Comment: @AmalMurali What do you mean ?

Comment: It returns `07/01/2014` no matter which year you input. For 2011 it should return `04/01/2011`

Comment: @AmalMurali, Am confused :P , dazz is right. Maybe you are saying it for the year 2011.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: The results returned by this function are incorrect. See here: https://eval.in/87071

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran no, he is not. His function returns the exact same result no matter what year you input into it. It should return the first Tuesday of the `$year` you give it, not the first Tuesday of 2014.

Comment: @AmalMurali Oh, you are right. Can't miss the `January`(month part).

Comment: Yep, including the month works.

Comment: @AmalMurali, Amazing!! Let me buy you a cup of tea ! :)

Comment: @xdazz: Didn't notice your edit. -1 changed to +1 ;)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work for me:

```
<?php

$first_tuesday = new DateTime("first Tuesday of January 2011");
echo $first_tuesday->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

?>
```

Putting it into functional form:

```
<?php

/**
 * @return DateTime Returns a DateTime object representing the
 *                  first Tuesday of the year
 */
function first_tuesday($year){
    $first_tuesday = new DateTime("first Tuesday of January $year");
    return $first_tuesday;
}

?>
```

If you just want the string in your format, then:

```
<?php

/**
 * @return DateTime Returns a string representing the first
 *                  Tuesday of the year in the d/m/Y format
 */
function first_tuesday($year){
    $first_tuesday = new DateTime("first Tuesday of January $year");
    return $first_tuesday->format('d/m/Y');
}

?>
```

You can read more about the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class in the PHP manual (which is also available in French, as that seems to be your native language based on the original question.)

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_of_year = strtotime("01.01.2011");
$first_tuesday = strtotime("tuesday", $start_of_year);

echo date('d.m.Y', $first_tuesday); // 04.01.2011
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
function first_tuesday($year)
{
    return date("d/m/Y",strtotime('first Tuesday january '.$year));
}
```

No need to use Objects, this is the fastest way of getting it.

Comment: wow great,,  that works perf

Comment: `Fastest` -- Irrelevant. You use DateTime not because it's fast, but because it's *better*.